# Flot: Graph with Date/Time as x axis not plotting correctly

Tags: javascript, flot

I am trying to display values over time, but no matter what data I try and plot, nothing appears on the graph. [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UEePE/3175/).

See code below. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="theGraph"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#theGraph{
    height:300px;
    width:500px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var graphData = [
    [new Date("2015-03-13T08:00").getTime(), 2],
    [new Date("2015-03-15T00:00").getTime(), 3]
];

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 2
        },
        points: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    lines: {
        show: true
    },
    points: {
        show: true
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: 'time',
        minTickSize: [1, 'hour'],
        min: new Date("2015-03-13T00:00").getTime(), 
        max: new Date("2015-03-15T08:00").getTime(), 
        timeformat: '%m/%d %H:%M'
    }
};

$.plot($('#theGraph'), graphData, options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.plot method takes the place holder / id of your div where you want to plot the graph. $.plot('#id',.....) also do the same.

And only one problem in your code $.plot(). The argument 'graphData' should be in [] braces as $.plot expects array of series data.

Modified Code:

```
$.plot($('#theGraph'), [graphData], options);
```

You can mention may data series to draw multiple lines in flot.

```
 var d1 = [], d2 =[], d3 =[];
 $.plot($('#theGraph'), [d1,d2,d3], options);
```